# Box-shadow with rotation Firefox bug

Tags: css, firefox

I have rendering problems in Mozilla Firefox if I'm rotating element with box shadow on it. I've found something on bugzilla and its marked as RESOLVED but its still not good. Can anyone tell me how can I fix this issue?

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="rotate">
    <p>Rotated Text Rotated Text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rotate {
   backface-visiblity: hidden;
   transform: rotate(-2deg) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}

.rotate p {
    display: inline;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #1E396E;
    box-shadow: 10px 0px 0px #1E396E, -10px 0px 0px #1E396E;
}
```

Bugzilla:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=536061

Browser version: 30.0